# Percorrer Array e remover palavras - Python

Tags: python

Criei uma lista usando um arquivo de texto e preciso de remover todas as palavras que tenham menos que 3 caracteres e mais que 8.

Estou com dúvidas em como percorrer a lista e criar uma outra lista sem as palavras que não atendem os critérios estabelecidos

Isto foi o que fiz até agora:

```
 `if __name__ == '__main__':

    with open('senhas.txt') as senha:                                           # ABRE O ARQUVO DE TEXTO COM AS PALAVRAS
        words = []                                                      # CRIA UMA NOVA LISTA PARA ARMAZENAR AS PALAVRAS
        for n in senha:                                # ESTRUTURA DE REPETIÇÃO PARA ADICIONAR AS PALAVRAS NA LISTA NOVA
            words.append(n.strip())                                                        # RETIRA OS ESPAÇOS EM BRANCO





','.join(words)  # SEPARA AS PALAVRAS EM APENAS UMA LINHA.

for i in range(len(words)):
    words[i] = words[i].lower()  # CONVERTE AS PALAVRAS EM MÍNUSCULO'
```

e as palavras com o arquivo está aqui: https://pastebin.com/FY3UxZtK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Em vez de remover os elementos de acordo com as regras estabelecidas, você pode nem sequer adicioná-los, então faça assim:

```
for n in senha:
    password = n.strip().lower()
    length = len(password)

    if (length >= 3 and length <= 8):
        words.append(password)
```

O código acima adiciona somente as palavras com tamanho >= 3 e <= 8, e também já deixa a palavra com letras minúsculas com o .lower(), tudo de uma vez só!

Answer (score 1):

Para ler cada linha de um arquivo (palavra) e adicionar somente as linhas que possuam tamanhos entre `3` e `8` em uma lista:

```
with open('senhas.txt') as f:
    words = []
    for ln in f:
        ln = ln.strip()
        if 3 <= len(ln) <= 8:
            words.append(ln)
```

Ou até mesmo:

```
with open('senhas.txt') as f:
    words = [ln.strip() for ln in f if 3 <= len(ln.strip()) <= 8]
```

Para converter o caso de todas as as palavras contidas na lista para minúsculo:

```
words = list(map(str.lower, words))
```

Tudo junto em uma linha só:

```
with open('senhas.txt') as f:
    words = [ln.strip().lower() for ln in f if 3 <= len(ln.strip()) <= 8]
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FrostyCreativeNaturallanguage)